# How can I create a script in Unix with following requirements?

Tags: unix, script

A script named `/root/backup.sh` on w01 that will backup the contents of /home

The script will:

- Create a tar archive named `/share/<YYYY><MM><DD>_w01.tar` where

  - YYYY represents the current year (i.e. 2014)
  - MM represents the current month (i.e. 11)
  - DD represents the current day of the month (i.e. 22)
- Log success and errors to `/tmp/backup.log`
- Exit with a non-zero return code if an error is encountered

Comment: Welcome to SU! We're not a script-writing service.  We can and will help you with specific problems in your scripting though;  But to do that we need to know what you've got so far, and exactly where you're getting stuck while implementing the script.

Comment: Thanks for that. Actually the point is that I am having a hard time in understanding what it is actually asking for. That's why I was asking here to write me a script so that I am able to understand and can write other scripts on my own. #Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007

Comment: "I am having a hard time in understanding what it is actually asking for."  I'm having the same problem with your question. :)  What is "It" in that sentence?  As for learning how to write scripts, there's a TONS of resources online for that, like [this one](http://linuxcommand.org/writing_shell_scripts.php), and [this one](http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/), for example.

Comment: Yes, I know... But I am talking about this particular script. The script is about backing up the contents of \home on workstation. Can you give me a headstart, if possible?

Answer (score 4):

The major factors you'll need to put the script together would be the following, (I would recommend you write each one as a separate bit of code, test it, then put it all together once you are happy):

- **File naming** (ie using the current date in your tarball name):
  As stated in an other answer, `man date` will give you some help, focus on the format section (eg `date +%Y%m`...)
- **Logging** (ie saving the output of the tar into a file you can refer to later):
  The first thing you'll need to decide is how long to save the log for, do you want previous day's attempts in there or just the most recent?  If you are saving multiple days' you will want to include a datestamp at the top of each new run so you can see where one finishes and the next starts.

  - `echo "here's a command" > /tmp/backup.log` will overwrite the contents of /tmp/backup.log, and put string "here's a command" in it's place.
  - `echo "here's a command" >> /tmp/backup.log` will keep any existing data in /tmp/backup.log, and append "here's a command" to the end of it.
  - `tar -cvf /share/foo.tar /home > /tmp/backup.log` will put only STDOUT (ie the usual 'I tar'ed these files' output) in the log, but any errors would not get captured.
  - `tar -cvf /share/foo.tar /home 2> /tmp/backup.log` will put only STDERR (ie only the errors) in the log.
  - `tar -cvf /share/foo.tar /home > /tmp/backup.log 2>&1` will put both STDOUT and STDERR in the log.

  Combine these to create exactly the right set of data in your log.
- **Error handling** (ie what to do if tar returns an error:
  A quick and dirty way to react to errors in a command is just to add `|| command_to_run_if_error` after your command.  This essentially says "Run these command in order until one succeeds", you can also use `&& command_to_run_if_success` which is like saying "Run these commands in order until one fails".

  - `command1 || command2`  Will run command1 and if it fails (non-zero exit code) will run command2.  If it succeeds, command2 will not be run.
  - `command1 && command2`  Will run command1 and if it fails, will stop and not run command2.  If command1 succeeds, only then will command2 be run.
  - A more complete handler of errors can be created using `if .. then .. else .. fi`

  eg
  `echo "About to run command1" >> logfile.log`
  `if command1 >> logfile.log`
  `then`
  `echo "All went well" >> logfile.log`
  `else`
  `echo "Something went wrong! ABORTING" >> logfile.log`
  `run_some_cleanup_command`
  `exit 1`
  `fi`

  Combine these to teach your script what to do each each failure case.

**Some other things to keep in mind:**

- Do you want to check there's space on /share to fit your tarball
  before you make it?
  Consider using `du -sk /home` to see how many KB
  it has to back up, and compare that with the amount of free space in
  `df -k /share`.  You can use shell commands like `[ $space_on_share
  -lt $data_in_home ] || exit 1` to abort rather than use up all your free space (you'd probably want it to log something helpful rather
  than just exit though).
- Do you want to back up *everything* in /home?
  Consider having a list of things to exclude to save space or protect
  privacy.
- Have you considered using compression to save space?
  some versions of tar accept the `-z`
  flag to use gzip compression, or you can specify STDOUT as the
  filename then pipe the output through gzip (`tar -cf - /home | gzip
  -c > /share/foo.tar.gz`)

Answer (score 2):

The key to starting any scripting problem is to break it down into small pieces. Code and  and test the first small pieces before adding more function.

For example

### step 1

You could start by wring a script that prints "Starting backup" and does nothing else.

### step 2

Once that works amend it to assign the output of the `date` command to a shell variable (e.g. `$today`) and print the contents of that variable.

### step 3

When step 2 is fully tested and working, browse `man date` and see how to change the output to get the "<YYYY><MM><DD>" output format you want.

and so on. If you get stuck at any point, search SuperUser (etc) for that specific tiny well-focussed question to see if there is an existing answer. If not write a carefully composed tightly-focussed question showing what you've done, what it did and what you wanted it to do instead. show runnable code but strip out any and all extraneous material.